# How do I approach mathematical proofs involving nested if-then statements?

Tags: analysis, logic, proof-writing

I'm new to proofs and trying to prove the following statement. I already have trouble writing the "automatic parts" of the proof at the beginning because I'm not sure what assumptions I can and should make given the nested if-then statements. I am finding that particularly confusing. Is there an algorithmic strategic approach to generally proving nested if-then-statements so that it's easier to see what should be defined and assumed in the beginning?

Here is the statement:

> Let $A,B$ be sets and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. If, for all $W,X \subseteq A$, if $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$, then $W \subseteq X$, then $f$ is injective.

I try breaking this down to the general form $(P \Rightarrow Q)\Rightarrow R$ such that

> P: "for all $W,X \subseteq A$, $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$"
>
> Q: "$W \subseteq X$"
>
> R: "$f$ is injective"

My proof is then as follows (line-for-line):

> (1) Suppose for all $W,X \subseteq A$, if $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$, then
> $W \subseteq X$.
>
> (2) Suppose $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$.
>
> (3) Let $y \in f(W)$.
>
> (4) Then, for all $y \in f(W)$, there exists $w \in W$ such that $f(w) = y$.
>
> (5) Since $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$, it follows that $y \in f(X)$ as well.
>
> (6) So, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.
>
> (7) Hence, $f(w)=f(x)$.
>
> (8) Based on the initial assumptions, from $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$ follows that $W \subseteq X$.
>
> (9) So, $w \in X$.

So, I have $f(w)=f(x)$ and $x,w \in X$. Since I'm trying to prove that $f$ is injective, I need to show that $x=w$ but I'm not seeing how to explicitly show this. My suspicion is that I might've already messed up at the very beginning because the nested if-then statements tend to give me trouble.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT

Thanks to everyone for suggestions and corrections. I believe that I now have a decent proof. Here again the statement:

> Let $A,B$ be sets and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. If, for all $W,X \subseteq A$, if $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$, then $W \subseteq X$, then $f$ is injective.

And the proof:

> (1) Suppose for all $W, X \subseteq A$, if $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$, then $W \subseteq X$.
>
> (2) Let $x, w \in A$ and suppose $f(x) = f(w)$.
>
> (3) Let $W = \{w\}$ and $X = \{x\}$.
>
> (4) Note that $f(W)=f(\{w\})=\{f(w)\}$ and $f(X)=f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}$.
>
> (5) Since $f(w) = f(x)$, it follows that $\{f(w)\} \subseteq \{f(x)\}$, i.e., $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$.
>
> (6) So, by the initial assumption, $W \subseteq X$, i.e., $\{w\} \subseteq \{x\}$.
>
> (7) Hence, $w = x$ and so $f$ is injective. $\square$

Comment: I don't know if this is really an Answer to this question, but it fits this specific example: when I see "If [complicated bit] then A is [adjective]", I mentally add some throat-clearing before the complicated bit: "If A has the property that [complicated bit], then A is [adjective]". This helps me, although for the life of me I can't explain why.

Comment: It doesn't look like the logical problem you were worried about has tripped you up in what you wrote. (There is a slight issue in (3), though: how do you know that $f(W)$ is not the empty set?). Still, you're not getting much use out of the $P\implies Q$" hypothesis yet. In general, to use a "for all [W,X]" assumption like (1) to prove something else, you're usually going to have to pick some clever(?) values [of W and X].

Comment: Okay fair: replace [complicated bit] with [complicated bit involving A].

Comment: Your proof is very confused. To show that the function $f\colon A \to B$ is injective, you need to *suppose* that you have $x, y \in A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$ and then *show* that consequently $x = y$. This is not at all what you are doing. The fact that you proved that $f(w) = f(x)$ for some specific $w$ and $x$ is irrelevant to showing that $f$ is injective. You went wrong already in step 2: instead of supposing that $f(W) \subseteq f(X)$ (which has no immediate relevance for showing that $f\colon A \to B$ is injective), you should suppose that you have $x, y \in A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: A more usual definition of an injective function: $\forall f,A, B:[f: A \to B \implies [Injective(f,A,B) \iff \forall x, y\in A:[f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y]]]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantifier that you placed in $\boldsymbol P$ applies to the entire inner conditional instead:

$\bigg($for each $W{,}X \:{\subseteq} A\;\Big(f(W)\subseteq f(X)\implies \boldsymbol Q(W,X)\Big)\bigg)\implies \boldsymbol R.$

This checks the universality of the inner conditional ($W$ and $X$ here are dummy variables) instead of the universality of the subset relation between the two images.

How you originally structured the translation left the last instance of $W$ and $X$ orphaned and free (not dummy variables): you can see this by substituting the dummy variable $W$ (and likewise the $X)$ in your proposed $\boldsymbol P$ with another letter.

---

**Addendum** (corresponding to the OP's EDIT)

Here's a clearer rewrite of your correction proof, where $W$ and $X$ are not confusingly arbitrary yet non-arbitrary:

- > Let $A,B$ be sets and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Suppose that for all $W,X \subseteq A,$ if $f(W) \subseteq f(X),$ then $W \subseteq X.$ Then $f$ is injective.

  Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary elements of $A$ such that $f(x)=f(y).$

  Then $\{x\},\{y\}\subseteq A$ and $\{f(x)\}\subseteq\{f(y)\},$ that is, $f(\{x\})\subseteq f(\{y\}).$

  By hypothesis, $\{x\}\subseteq\{y\}.$

  But they are singletons; so in fact $x=y.$

  Hence, $f$ is injective.